How to serialise a TensorFlow Hub "KerasLayer" to enable parallel computing with libraries like joblib or Ray?
To work within the constraints of a Kaggle competition, I'm using a pre-trained EfficientNetv2-m model that's loaded into my Kaggle notebook using TensorFlow Hub (I can't see another way of loading this model without it).
I load the model, add my own layers to the end and train those additional layers on the training image dataset. The complete model is then used for inference on a testing image dataset.
As the testing dataset is massive, I need to process 2 images in parallel rather than 1 at a time to complete within the 12 hour time limit. Other teams have done this with success, although not using TensorFlow Hub models.
I've tried to use the Ray and joblib libraries for parallel processing and both are giving me the same error: They can't de-serialise the "KerasLayer" in my model, which is the Efficientnet model from TensorFlow Hub. I've tried a few ways to serialise the model as a custom object but all unsuccessfully (I'm not very experienced and very much still learning too).
How can I properly serialise a TensorFlow Hub model for parallel processing?
Here's some of my code below for more context too:

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

print("TF version:", tf.__version__)
print("Hub version:", hub.__version__)
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') else "NOT AVAILABLE")

TF version: 2.13.0
Hub version: 0.14.0
GPU is available
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import applications, layers, models, optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.utils import Sequence, to_categorical

model_handle = "/kaggle/input/efficientnet-v2/tensorflow2/imagenet21k-m-feature-vector/2"

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + (3,)),
        hub.KerasLayer(model_handle, trainable=do_fine_tuning),
        layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dropout(0.2),
        layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')  # 6 units for 6 categories
    ])


Then the model is trained and ready for inference
The 'image_prediction' function below loads an image and makes a model.predict, which is where the error occurs
# Initialize Ray
ray.init(num_cpus=4, num_gpus=1, _temp_dir='/kaggle/working/', _plasma_directory='/kaggle/working/')

model_ref = ray.put(model)

# Define the image processing function as a Ray remote function
@ray.remote(num_gpus=0.5, num_cpus=2, max_calls=1)
def process_image(row, source_directory, model_ref):
    image_filename = ("%s.png" % row[0])  # Getting the image filename from column [0]
    source_path = os.path.join(source_directory, image_filename)

    # Here, add your image_prediction logic as before
    image_class_index = image_prediction(source_path, model_ref)
    print("Image %s classified as %s" % (row[0], image_class_index))
    return row[0], image_class_index

# List to store future objects returned by invoking the remote function
futures = []

for index, row in test_df.iterrows():
    # Submit tasks to be executed in parallel
    future = process_image.remote(row, source_directory, model_ref)
    futures.append(future)

# Retrieve results
results = ray.get(futures)

# Process results
for result in results:
    row_id, image_class_index = result
    # Assuming 'row_id' can be used to find the correct index in `submission_df`
    submission_df.at[submission_df.index[submission_df[0] == row_id].tolist()[0], 'label'] = image_class_index

# Don't forget to shutdown Ray at the end of your script
ray.shutdown()


RayTaskError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 26
     23     futures.append(future)
     25 # Retrieve results
---> 26 results = ray.get(futures)
     28 # Process results
     29 for result in results:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/_private/auto_init_hook.py:24, in wrap_auto_init.<locals>.auto_init_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     21 @wraps(fn)
     22 def auto_init_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
     23     auto_init_ray()
---> 24     return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py:103, in client_mode_hook.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    101     if func.__name__ != "init" or is_client_mode_enabled_by_default:
    102         return getattr(ray, func.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
--> 103 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/_private/worker.py:2547, in get(object_refs, timeout)
   2545     worker.core_worker.dump_object_store_memory_usage()
   2546 if isinstance(value, RayTaskError):
-> 2547     raise value.as_instanceof_cause()
   2548 else:
   2549     raise value

RayTaskError: ray::process_image() (pid=2721, ip=172.19.2.2)
  At least one of the input arguments for this task could not be computed:
ray.exceptions.RaySystemError: System error: Cannot deserialize object of type `KerasLayer`. If `KerasLayer` is a custom class, please register it using the `@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()` decorator.
traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/pickle_utils.py", line 48, in deserialize_model_from_bytecode
    raise e
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/pickle_utils.py", line 46, in deserialize_model_from_bytecode
    model = saving_lib.load_model(filepath, safe_mode=False)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py", line 275, in load_model
    raise e
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py", line 240, in load_model
    model = deserialize_keras_object(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py", line 704, in deserialize_keras_object
    instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/sequential.py", line 473, in from_config
    layer = layer_module.deserialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/serialization.py", line 276, in deserialize
    return serialization_lib.deserialize_keras_object(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py", line 579, in deserialize_keras_object
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Cannot deserialize object of type `KerasLayer`. If `KerasLayer` is a custom class, please register it using the `@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()` decorator.

I tried to register a custom class as the error message suggested but have not found a successful way of doing this yet. I tried both decorators below:
#@keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package='HubLayers')
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(package='HubLayers')
class KerasLayer(hub.KerasLayer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(KerasLayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

I believe I could be missing more from the custom class for this to work. I tried to add 'get_config' function to the class as the Keras documentation suggests but again unsuccessful.
